# Change Variable back to original value after Regex matching

Tags: c#, regex

I just "finished" expanding my Palindrome Tester, made in C#. To allow for phrases I added a simple regex match for all non-alphanumeric characters. At the end of the program it states " is(n't) a palindrome." But now with the regex it prints the no spaces/punctuation version of it.

I would like to be able to print the original user input. How do I do that?

Here is my program: http://gist.github.com/384565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Calling `ToLower()` doesn't do anything by itself. Strings are immutable, meaning that it's impossible to *modify* an instance of string. The `ToLower()` function returns a new string, so you have to store that value in a variable (either the same or a new one).
2. To return the value passed into the function, just create a new string variable.

Like this:

```
public static string Tester(string input)
{
    string pattern = "\\W";

    string data = Regex.Replace(input.ToLower(), pattern, String.Empty);

    if (data == StringHelper.ReverseString(data))
    {
        Console.Write(input); Console.Write(" is a Palindrome.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(input); Console.Write(" isn't a Palindrome.");
    }

    return input;
}
```